# How to pass a List query in Java to cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In this query, I need to pass a ArrayList of strings to the RE in the cypher query. How to modify this version to make it work for the purpose.

```
public String query_partial_match(String skuid, List<String> attrKey) {

        return "MATCH (s:Product {id:'" + skuid + "'})-[r]-> (o) " +
                "WHERE " +
                "(o:ExAttrs OR o:ProdAttrs) AND " +
                "any(key in keys(o) WHERE key =~'(?i).*(" + attrKey + ").*') " +
                "return o";
    }
```

I am using JDK 1.8 API，and the Neo4j Native API, SDK. Thanks,

Comment: Why not pass the `skuid` and `attrKey` as parameters instead of manual constructing a query?

Comment: @stdob--how would that query look like per your suggestion? This is my current way to generate query dynamically and then send the query string to the 'execute' method.

Comment: I think you may want to review the [parameter documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/). You pass a map of parameters along with the query string when you execute the query. Just include a list as one of your parameters, and access the parameter in your query using the `$paramName` style syntax.